# py2neo cursor appears to consume everything into memory rather than stream data

Tags: python-3.x, csv, neo4j, py2neo

I am running a query to a Neo4J server, which I expect to return >100M rows (but just a few columns) and then write the results into a CSV file. This works well for queries that return up to 10-20M rows but becomes tricky as the resultant rows go up into 10^8 numbers.

I thought, writing the results row by row (ideally buffered) should be a solution but the `csv.Writer` appears to only write into disk once the whole code executes (i.e. at the end of the iteration), rather than in chunks as expected. In this example below, I tried explicitly flushing the file (which did not work). I also do not get any output on stdout indicating that the iteration is not occurring as intended.

The mem usage of the process is growing rapidly however, over 12GBs last I checked. That makes me think that the cursor is trying to get all the data before starting iteration, which it should not do, unless I misunderstood something.

Any ideas?

```
from py2neo import Graph
import csv

cursor = g.run(query)
with open('bigfile.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = cursor.keys()
    writer = csv.Writer(csvfile)

#    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
#    writer.writeheader()
    i = 0
    j = 1
    for rec in cursor:
#        writer.writerow(dict(rec))
        writer.writerow(rec.values())
        i +=1 
        if i == 50000:
            print(str(i*j) + '...')
            csvfile.flush()
            i = 0
            j +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the main problem the size of the query, rather than the method of writing the results to the CSV file? If you're chunking the writing process, perhaps you should chunk the querying process aswell, since the results are stored in memory while the file writing is taking place.

Comment: I have thought about that as well, but it should be on the server and not on the client, right? The server has much more memory to play with than what I have on my laptop. Additionally, chunking the query isn't necessarily trivial either, since in order to use SKIP-LIMIT combo, one needs to ORDER BY which would also impose processing all records first

Comment: If the sole purpose of the server is to serve data to a couple of clients it could work, but otherwise the volume of the data can impose a lot of stress on the machine, so other processes might suffer. I'd still say that the better approach would be doing a conditional select for the count of records, then chunking it up and writing the results to a file server side. After that, you might want to stream the contents of that temporary file to a client aswell, since the same problem will occur with server-client transfer.
Either way you're going to lose memory or clock cycles.